# Qt OpenGL, QOpenGLWidget and VSync

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am working on a GUI application which runs on RedHat 7.2, with Qt 5.6, originally the graphics were all rendered using Qt native functions, however the video display and other widgets show tearing.

So I went about re-writing all the graphics replacing the QWidget based classes with classes derived from QOpenGLWidget and QOpenGLFunctions.

The tearing is still present, I've read online that calling:

```
    window.setAnimating(true);
```

> Use OpenGLWindow::setAnimating(true) for render() to be called at the vertical refresh rate, assuming vertical sync is enabled in the underlying OpenGL drivers.

Taken from: [OpenGL Window Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html)

However I can't find an equivalent method for QOpenGLWidget, is there an equvalent?  How do I ensure that QOpenGLWidgets are only rendered with vsync?

Comment: Have you enabled VSync? It can be a pain as it is platform dependent and the video drivers may force it off ignoring your request to turn it on using `wglSwapInterval`

Comment: @Geoffrey, is this the Qt of enabling vsync ?  I tried calling setSwapInterval(1), which according to the documentation is the default, but no better.